# MySQL: Do you need to use backticks on column names when using the dot to refer to a table name (table_name.`column`)

Tags: mysql

When using backticks with MySQL so column names don't collide with reserved words:

```
SELECT `count`, `type`
FROM    table1
```

Do you still need to use backticks to prevent it colliding with reserved words when you're doing this:

```
SELECT  table1.count, table1.type
FROM    table1
```

Should you still add the backticks like this:

```
SELECT  table1.`count`, table1.`type`
FROM    table1
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax (without `backticks`) will work on

- MySQL - see [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jbAaC841UbefmuwdtGPQh9/0) and [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jbAaC841UbefmuwdtGPQh9/1),

See SQL at the bottom of the post.

(tl;dr) The answer to the question "MySQL: **Do you need to use backticks** on column names when using the dot to refer to a table name" is "**No, you do not need to use backticks!**".

See also

- PostgreSQL - [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iJaBmL8WZkSyG8HcwZVg6t/1),
- MS SQL Server - [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=7e826f9097e2b688ced592e00006189d),
- Oracle - [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=7e826f9097e2b688ced592e00006189d).

However, I beg of you, if you value your own sanity, do **NOT EVER** use [SQL keywords](https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/coding-standards/list-of-sql-reserved-words). `COUNT` and `TYPE` are such words.  It makes debugging a **nightmare** and is completely unnecessary anyway. Use identifiers such as `my_count` or `thing_type` instead. Just because you **can** drive your car over a cliff, doesn't mean that you **should**!

Most (all?) modern `RDBMS`s have (at least) 64 character(*) identifiers. That_is_more_than_enough_dont_you_think?

Furthermore (and very importantly) if you use the superfluous (and highly annoying) `backtick`, you'll be bunched when cutting and pasting your SQL to different servers - my advice is to avoid at all costs. It's no longer required and is tricky to type!

Get some SQL naming conventions off the web ([example](http://leshazlewood.com/software-engineering/sql-style-guide/)), pick one and **stick to it**! This is somewhat of a religious topic (an "ecumenical matter" in the immortal words of [Fr. Jack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Father_Ted_characters#Father_Jack_Hackett)!). Read around and decide for yourself!

My own preference is for table names to be singular (a table is a collection anyway), SQL in UPPER CASE and identifiers_in_lower_case_with_underscores - makes reading easy!

You (and those who come after you) will be eternally grateful!

(*) from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/756569/470530), Oracle was 30 bytes up and including 12.1, but it's now 128 bytes - almost a tweet! :-)

Now, consider the following DDL, DML, query and response:

(**simple, legible and portable!**)

=========== DDL and DML ==================

```
CREATE TABLE table1
(
  my_count INTEGER,
  my_type  VARCHAR (10),
  count    INTEGER,
  type     VARCHAR (10)
);

INSERT INTO table1 VALUES 
(1, 'type1', 34, 'type1_bis'),
(2, 'type2', 23, 'type2_bis'),
(3, 'type3', 56, 'type3_bis'),
(4, 'type4', 78, 'type4_bis'),
(5, 'type5', 90, 'type5_bis');
```

And a simple query:

```
SELECT 
  t.my_count,  -- see second MySQL sample!
  t.my_type,
  t.count,
  t.type
FROM
  table1 t;
```

Results:

```
my_count    my_type     count       type
1             type1        34  type1_bis
2             type2        23  type2_bis
3             type3        56  type3_bis
4             type4        78  type4_bis
5             type5        90  type5_bis
```

Comment: And... Don't clutter column names with the table name:  `my_table_my_column`.  After all, if you need to qualify the column, there is the "dot" syntax that this Question started with!